# How do I open a Tensorflow saver on another computer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

i'm using tensorflow 1.0 on ubuntu 16

I'm using a saver as folows, from an example online:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(name='saver', write_version=tf.train.SaverDef.V2)
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.save_path, save_model_secs=0, save_summaries_secs=0, saver=saver)
```

It runs and trains fine, but I can't run the sample mode from another computer because the save path persists on as the old directory for the other computer.

the error I get is something like this:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on /home/oldpc/model/-54: Not found: /home/oldpc/model
     [[Node: saver/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_saver/Const_0, saver/RestoreV2/tensor_names, saver/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: saver/restore_all/NoOp_1/_20 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_56_saver/restore_all/NoOp_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

The path it should load, as I'm passing it via cmd line, should be --save_path="home/newpc/model/"

the code is from [here](http://deeplearningathome.com/2016/10/Text-generation-using-deep-recurrent-neural-networks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a relative save path, not an absolute one. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to change an absolute store path once used. I ran into this same problem too and was unable to change the path until I used a relative path.